# Blazor JSInvokable without static function

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

I have my Blazor component with some `JavaScript` code. When there is a click detected by the JavaScript code, I want to call an `JSInvokable` function in my Blazor component to update the UI.

So, I created a function like this

```
[JSInvokable]
public static async Task ChangeTab(string val)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

in the `JavaScript`, I added the following line:

```
DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('myComponent', 'ChangeTab', tabText);
```

This code is working and the function `ChangeTab` receives the value I expected. The problem is that this function is `static`. So, I can't change the variables. I tried to change the code like this (*ActivatePage* is a function in the component)

```
[JSInvokable("ChangeTab")]
public async Task ChangeTab(string val)
{
    ActivatePage(val);
}
```

but in this case I get an error because the function is not static.

> Error: System.ArgumentException: The assembly 'PSC.Blazor.Components.ScrollTabs' does not contain a public invokable method with [JSInvokableAttribute("ChangeTab")]

[image]

I checked the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but I don't understand how to change the `JSInvokable` function to not be `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `DotNetObjectReference` of the component (which has the JSInvokable method) to JavaScript. This is usually done after the component renders.

`Example.razor`:

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {
    private DotNetObjectReference<Example>? dotNetHelper;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            dotNetHelper = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Helpers.setDotNetHelper", dotNetHelper);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable("ChangeTab")]
    public async Task ChangeTab(string val)
    {
        ActivatePage(val);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dotNetHelper?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then use that reference to call your component's method from JavaScript:

```html
<script>
  class Helpers {
    static dotNetHelper;

    static setDotNetHelper(value) {
      Helpers.dotNetHelper = value;
    }

    static async changeTab(tabText) {
      await Helpers.dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('ChangeTab', tabText);
    }
  }

  window.Helpers = Helpers;
</script>
```

Call `Helpers.changeTab` from JavaScript when you want to change the tab.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0#invoke-an-instance-net-method)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the following:

#### MyComponent.razor

```
@code {
    DotNetObjectReference<MyComponent> _componentReference => DotNetObjectReference.Create(this); //Create an object reference for JS

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("MyJS.CacheMyComponent", _componentReference); //Send object reference to JS to cache
    }

    [JSInvokable("ChangeTab")]
    public async Task ChangeTab(string val)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
window.MyJS = {
    MyComponentReference: null,
    CacheMyComponent: function (componentReference) {
        MyJS.MyComponentReference = componentReference; //Cache
    },
    ChangeTabOnMyComponent: function (tabText) {
        MyJS.MyComponentReference.invokeMethodAsync('ChangeTab', tabText); //Use cached reference
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. It is useful. Generally speaking, the other solution was easier to implement in my code.