# Blazor DotNet.invokeMethodAsync doesn't call C# function (no errors)

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I've a JS rendered HTML button:

```
'<button onclick="fnDisplayCustomer(54)">Click me!</button>'
```

Which successfully calls the function:

```
fnDisplayCustomer = function (customerId) {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('displayCustomer', customerId)
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)            
        });
}
```

The JS function should then call the C# function:

```
[JSInvokable]
public int displayCustomer(int customerId)
{
    return customerId;
}
```

The JS is in its own file called at the bottom of the page's razor file.

Debugging through the JS in browser, the DotNet.invokeMethodAsync is hit, but the C# method isn't. No errors are thrown, but a break point insidethe C# method is never hit, and the console.log line in the invokeMethodAsync function doesn't fire.

I read that methods called by invokeMethodAsync need to be static (this appears to be incorrect) but I still tried:

```
[JSInvokable]
public static int displayCustomer(int customerId)
{
    return customerId;
}
```

The assembly name can be specified in the invokeMethodAsync, but as I'm calling the script from the page I'm unsure if this is needed. Also I'm not entirely sure of its function as the assembly name isn't the the name of the page class which contains my method I want to call. I could have method in all of my classes called "displayCustomer" all doing different things, I fail to see how specifying the assembly name and a method name gets it to the specific method of that name I want.

I initially call the JS from C# using

> Microsoft.JSInterop;

Calling JS from the C# is working fine.

I'm unsure how to diagnose my issue as I'm not getting any JS or C# errors/warnings.

Comment: Does this help? [Blazor JSInvokable without static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74347062/blazor-jsinvokable-without-static-function)

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Been trying that solution, it looks like it should address my issue, but I get the error "Could not find 'Helpers.setDotNetHelper' ('Helpers' was undefined)." on the C# line "await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Helpers.setDotNetHelper", dotNetHelper);" I've added the helpers class to my script, but  InvokeVoidAsync doesn't see it

Comment: Here's the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-a-dotnetobjectreference-to-an-individual-javascript-function) about it.